# Test a excel file using Selenium

Tags: asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a web application in ASP.NET and C# that exports some data on a click of a button. How to test the contents of the Excel file from the exported file in a location on a system using Selenium?

I know by saving Excel file as HTML we can open Excel sheet as a web page. But I am not able to find a way to open it from C# code.

Comment: You can't test excel with selenium.  Either using an excel parser or create one yourself.

Comment: @JeffC Thanks! I did an update on my questions

Comment: Please don't export an Excel sheet as HTML with the sole purpose of validating the contents using Selenium. Use C# to open and validate the contents of the Excel sheet.

Comment: Why is that? I have a web application that generates multiple Excel files. So by opening Excel file as HTML, I do not have to develop a framework for reading CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is for automating web/http transactions and nothing else.

Read this article on MSDN that will give you some info how to work with C# and Excel: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188489.aspx

Some more brief information: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/302084/how-to-automate-microsoft-excel-from-microsoft-visual-c--net

Comment: It makes sense! But is there a way in testing excel files from c# instead of using a CSV reader, open Excel as HTML and test using Selenium

Comment: With less than 20 lines of code you can open a Excel file in C# and do some simple validation.. To convert the excel to HTML and then do the validation on that does not make any sense at all unless the sole purpose is to test the actual HTML version of an excel sheet. That is a different question then what you asked originally.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that with help from google

```
Application app = new Application();
Workbook Wrk =app.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/Desktop/Delete/filename");
Wrk.SaveAs("c:/Users/Desktop/InvoiceMeet.html", XlFileFormat.xlHtml);
```

This will covert an Excel file to a browser file. Thanks!